# User Name is not fetching after Hosting in IIS :: LDAP C# but working fine in local host

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is my code to fetch the username.

```
string user = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
            user = user.Substring(user.Length - 7, 7);
           // lblusername.Text = user;

            DirectorySearcher dssearch = new DirectorySearcher();
            dssearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + user + ")";
            SearchResult sresult = dssearch.FindOne();

            if (sresult != null)
            {
                 DirectoryEntry dsresult = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=somename,DC=com");
                 dsresult = sresult.GetDirectoryEntry();

                 lblusername.Text = dsresult.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();

            }
```

IIS is having Windows Authentication Mode.
also defined in web confiq

Comment: can you please explain more ? i mean what exact issue are you facing.. ? error or configuration issue ?

Comment: it is not giving the result while running on iis(after publishing to IIS)

Comment: but it is giving result "user display name" while running on local host.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that 'Anonymous Access' is disabled for that website on IIS.

To verify this, follow below steps:

1. Open IIS
2. Select your site from 'Sites' section shown in left area of IIS
3. Double click on 'Authentication' option under 'IIS' section
4. Status of 'Anonymous Access' should be disabled. If it is 'Enabled' then change it to 'Disabled'

This should work.

Comment: I have checked and it is working in my local environment as well as in IIS. Which version of IIS you are using? And Under which .NET framework you have developed your application? Also, while creating project in Visual Studio which 'Authentication' type you have selected?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day I resolved it by removing the default windows saved credential.